# Force file deletion on Windows

Tags: windows, files

Often on my development workstation (on which I am administrator and the only user), I am unable to delete files by deleting the root folder - despite having recursively taken ownership of the tree.  I am presuming that this is due to the file being locked by another process.

What (scriptable) options do I have that can help here?

Comment: I should have also said that I'm on 2008 x64.

Comment: Be careful with solutions which close the file handle, since they might cause unpredictable corruption. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.windowsconfidential.aspx for details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use **[LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/)** to see which process is blocking the deletion of a file. It's a freeware tool for Windows (32 bit and 64 bit versions available) which integrates itself into the Windows Explorer context menu.

> It is a free tool to delete files
>   blocked by something you do not know.
>   LockHunter is useful for fighting
>   against malware, and other programs
>   that are blocking files without a
>   reason. Unlike other similar tools it
>   deletes files into the recycle bin so
>   you may restore them if deleted by
>   mistake.

[image: LockHunter Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [lockhunter.com](http://lockhunter.com/images/mainScreenshot.png))</sub>

Comment: Looks good - 64 bit support too :)

Comment: Having now used this software, I like it even more than Unlocker (which I've used for ages when on 32 bit OS).  This puppy is slicker to use and works on x64 too, which is great!  Okay, it's not scriptable, but I have added a feature request on their site that is becomes so...I'll wait and see.  Thanks splattne!

Answer (score 3):

With [MoveFile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx) from Sysinternals you can schedule the deletion for next reboot or you could try to unlock the file with [Unlocker](http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/).

Comment: Thanks jonelf - unfortunately Unlocker does not currently support 64 bit OS and I don't want to have to reboot to delete the files.

Answer (score 1):

I posted [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/18783/how-do-i-delete-a-locked-file-in-windows/19046#19046) on this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/18783/how-do-i-delete-a-locked-file-in-windows/). Basically I use Systernal's Process Monitor to see what's locking the file. This [How-to](http://blog.shijaz.com/2008/10/unlocking-files-that-are-in-use.html) is great on how-to use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is locked via another process then use [ffunlocker](http://www.diamondcs.com.au/freeutilities/fileunlocker.php).

It isn't a scriptable solution but it is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

unlocker is great for doing this [right click, unlock]